System shows 4 RAM Slots available, but only 2 are visible
In my task manager "Memory" tab under performance, It tells me that 4 RAM slots are available. But when I open the cover of my laptop, there are only 2 RAM slots visible. Task manager displayed that I have used 2 out of 4 RAM slots. (The 2 RAM slots are what I currently use) So where are the other RAM slots? And if there is 2 more RAM slots, how do I utilize them?
I use a Asus X42JY laptop with a 2GB DDR3 RAM installed by default.

what is the make and model of your laptop?
And to use them once found, you would buy more sticks of ram that is compatible with your laptop and install them.

Often times there are 2 additional slots on the other side of the motherboard. You have to completely remove it and flip it over to check. For the model you have listed, there are only 2 slots. Not sure why task manager is reporting 4 slots. You can see what both sides look like on the iFixit teardown guide.. The maximum supported amount of memory is 4gb. You can swap your 2x 1gb sticks for 2x 2gb sticks of "DDR3 PC3-8500 1066MHz SODIMM" memory.

You don't. Its likely the chipset which is common to other designs supports 4 ram slots. There's only 2 physical ram slots  but its entirely possible to use the same chipset for 4 sticks. The tolerances needed for ram means it needs to be designed into the motherboard, and can't be added after the fact to a motherboard. Not having seperate chips for 2 or 4 slot costs saves on production and stocking costs.
